# c# wpf - cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I want to add tooltip in listboxItem but it starts problem when there is `DisplayMemberPath`. Error message said:

> cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate.

When I removed `DisplayMemberPath`, tooltip in each list item is working. But i dont want to remove `DisplayMememberPath` because I need it. How to solve this problem?

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lstToys" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" DisplayMemberPath="Toys"
            MouseDoubleClick="lstToys_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ToolTip="Here is a tooltip"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Put that path in the DataTemplate Binding

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`DisplayMemberPath` is, in effect, a template for a single property, shown in a `TextBlock`. If you set:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lstToys" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" DisplayMemberPath="Toys">
</ListBox>
```

It is equivalent to:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lstToys" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Toys}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You can simply remove the `DisplayMemberPath` path and use the value in your `DataTemplate`'s `Binding`:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lstToys" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Toys}" ToolTip="Here is a tooltip!"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Edit**

If you want to set a `ToolTip` but keep the `DisplayMemberPath`, you can do it at the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lstToys" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" DisplayMemberPath="Toys">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Here's a tooltip!"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

I'd advise against it. Remember that use  `DisplayMemberPath` stops you from any complex binding in your data template.

Comment: but i dont want to remove DisplayMemberPath because it is linked to some functions i created.

Comment: @user235973457 See my edit. You still can't put an `ItemTemplate` if you have `DisplayMemberPath`. If you needs become more complex for templating, you will need to change your logic (I don't think using DisplayMemberPath for custom logic outside the view is a good idea).

Comment: worked for me too. thank you so much to save my time.

Comment: but this is not applied to selected value as after selection my combo box displays whole text and so it's width increase as it's auto. Any help for selected item too?