# A way of using DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate together?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, itemtemplate

As shown in the XAML below, I have a `ListView` with a label in it; And in that label is a `ContextMenu`. The `ContextMenu` is in a `DataTemplate` and resources by an `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView`. Secondly, I have a `DisplayMemberPath` property which links to a method in one of my classes.

```
 <ListView x:Name="TitleList" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" DisplayMemberPath="Title">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="20,20,0,0"/>
            </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
                    <Label Content="{Binding .}" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Label.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Add Question" Click="AddQuestion"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Edit Title"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Delete Title"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Reposition Title"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Label.ContextMenu>
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

The problem I am having is that `DisplayMemberPath` and `ItemTemplate` can not both be properties of my `ListView` at once, yet I need both.

**Is there another way to have a `ContextMenu` without using `ItemTemplate`, or is there another solution?**

**EDIT:**

Been trying to complete this and have tried changing these:

```
<ListView x:Name="TitleList" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectedValuePath="Title">

<ListView x:Name="TitleList" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TextSearch.TextPath="Title">
```

Both of these let me right click and it will display the menu, but the string shows up as `MVVMModel.NewTitleClass`.

Comment: Side note - your code behind event handler is not very MVVM

Comment: @Gusdor How do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# wpf - cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273415/c-sharp-wpf-cannot-set-both-displaymemberpath-and-itemtemplate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the DisplayMemberPath. You are using a custom template for how a ListViewItem should appear. The issue is with your label's Content binding. Change it to this (or tinker around with it a bit if this doesn't work):

```
Content="{Binding Title}"
```

Another option is that when you don't specify the property to display when binding a control, it uses the ToString() result. If you haven't overridden this, it will show the fully qualified class name. So you could override the ToString() like this:

```
public override ToString()
{
   return Title;
}
```

The first option would be the best choice though.

Answer (score -1):

> ... I need both ...

**No, you do not**

Simply add an extra element in your `DataTemplate` to display the `Title` of each item.

Comment: How would I Achieve this?