# WPF combobox with bound selected value and static items not recognizing selection on init

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I need to have a combobox with two values. The first should have a custom name, while the second should use the underlying bound object's properties. Both items are values on the VM, and I'm able to bind all of it successfully.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="StaticComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StaticComboBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:StaticUIVm}"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
         SelectedValuePath="Tag"
                SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
         <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Custom Display Text 111"
                          Tag="{Binding FirstValue}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding SecondValue.Item2}"
                          Tag="{Binding SecondValue}" />
         </ComboBox.Items>
      </ComboBox>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace StaticComboBox
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = new StaticUIVm();
      }
   }
}
```

StaticUIVm.cs

```
using StaticComboBox.Annotations;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace StaticComboBox
{
   public class StaticUIVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public Tuple<long, string> FirstValue { get; set; }

      public Tuple<long, string> SecondValue { get; set; }

      private Tuple<long, string> _selectedValue;

      public Tuple<long, string> SelectedValue
      {
         get { return _selectedValue; }
         set
         {
            _selectedValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public StaticUIVm()
      {
         FirstValue = new Tuple<long, string>(1, "Some Static Value");
         SecondValue = new Tuple<long, string>(2, "Some Other Static Value");

         SelectedValue = FirstValue;
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is that despite the bindings working correctly for the items and displaying and when I as a user select a value, the combobox isn't reflecting the correct selection when initializing the VM class. Meaning, it doesn't select FirstValue. This doesn't make sense to me as the reference should be exactly the same, and I've confirmed that the value is in fact changing on the VM during initialization. I've definitely initialized values in the constructor and had them respected and displayed on load, so I'm a little confused as to where I'm going wrong here.

**EDIT**

I've accepted mm8's answer, but had to make a few additional tweaks to the XAML to get it to behave as needed. I needed to be able to trigger the custom text based on the ID value of the items, which was set at run time. Because of this a simple DataTrigger would not work so I had to use a MultiBinding. The MultiBinding broke the display when an item was selected (as described in [ComboBox.ItemTemplate not displaying selection properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816684/combobox-itemtemplate-not-displaying-selection-properly)) so I had to set IsEditable to false. The full combobox is below.

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            IsEditable="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock>
              <TextBlock.Style>
                 <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text"
                            Value="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Value="True">
                          <DataTrigger.Binding>
                             <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LongEqualToLongMultiBindingDisplayConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Id" />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.FirstValue.Id" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}" />
                             </MultiBinding>
                          </DataTrigger.Binding>
                          <Setter Property="Text"
                                  Value="Custom Display Text 111" />
                       </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                 </Style>
              </TextBlock.Style>
           </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

This XAML in combination with the suggestions from mm8's answer (setting up a collection which is initialized at runtime from the two provided values) did the trick.

Comment: I use WPF comboboxes quite a bit and I have found it is much easier to bind them to an `ObservableCollection` and then use `SelectedIndex` to set initial display values.

Comment: @DavidBentley Yeah, I can definitely implement this like that, but I was hoping to avoid adding too much overhead to the class as in reality I use FirstValue and SecondValue repeatedly through the class, so in order for that to work I'd also need a collection on top of the individual references.

Comment: I got it to work without using a collection...answer to come...

Comment: So I updated my answer and it does what you want with less code and without having to use an `IEnumerable` or `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply expose a collection of selectable items from your view model? This is how to solve this using MVVM:

```
public class StaticUIVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Tuple<long, string> FirstValue { get; set; }
    public Tuple<long, string> SecondValue { get; set; }

    private Tuple<long, string> _selectedValue;
    public Tuple<long, string> SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            _selectedValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<long, string>> Values { get; }

    public StaticUIVm()
    {
        FirstValue = new Tuple<long, string>(1, "Some Static Value");
        SecondValue = new Tuple<long, string>(2, "Some Other Static Value");
        Values = new Tuple<long, string>[2] { FirstValue, SecondValue };
        SelectedValue = SecondValue;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Item2}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Item1}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Custom Display Text 111" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

You might even remove the `FirstValue` and `SecondValue` properties. The custom text is defined in the view but the actual options to choose from is defined in the view model.

Comment: This almost accomplishes my goal. There are two drawbacks which may be due to our code: 1. I need to have the value of the datatrigger be bound to Item1's ID (as the object represented by Item1 isn't constant and determined at run time), and 2. the selected record is always showing the class name, not the custom text or the display path I set by default.

Comment: @Marisa: It should display the contents of the TextBlock? That is "Custom Display Text 111" or "Some Other Static Value".

Comment: It is in my abbreviated test project, but not my actual project. Likely just a binding weirdness I have to sort out first.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it got me 99% of the way to a solution. Please see my edit in the question for the full resolution.

Comment: This is basically what I said originally by using a collection or `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @DavidBentley And while I wanted to avoid using a solution like this, it became clear it would not work long term. I appreciate your help, but the code was not working out without using a collection.

Answer (score 0):

MAJOR EDITS:

So when I first added an answer, I was trying to use what you already had instead of demonstrating how I would do it. WPF is both flexible and constrictive in certain ways and I have often found myself working around problems. Your question is actually quite simple when done using a different approach. Many of my programs have `ComboBox` controls and although I normally populate with a collection, a similar principle can be applied by using a helper data class over a `Tuple`. This will add significantly more flexibility and be more robust.

I added the property `SelectedIndex` and bound it to an `int` in your datacontext class. I also changed `SelectedValue` to `SelectedItem` as it it far superior in this use case.

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
              SelectedValuePath="Tag"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

        <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding FirstValue.display}"
                          Tag="{Binding FirstValue}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding SecondValue.display}"
                          Tag="{Binding SecondValue}" />
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
```

Datacontext Class, Data Class, and Extension Method:

So, I moved your property changed event over to a separate class. I recommend doing this as it makes it reusable. It is especially handy for the Data Class. Now in the constructor we set the selected item AND the selected index.

```
public class StaticUIVm : PropertyChangeHelper
{
    private ComboBoxDataType _FirstValue;
    public ComboBoxDataType FirstValue
    {
        get { return _FirstValue; }
        set
        {
            _FirstValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ComboBoxDataType _SecondValue { get; set; }
    public ComboBoxDataType SecondValue
    {
        get { return _SecondValue; }
        set
        {
            _SecondValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ComboBoxDataType _SelectedItem;
    public ComboBoxDataType SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _SelectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _SelectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public StaticUIVm(string dynamicName)
    {
        FirstValue = new ComboBoxDataType() { id = 1, data = "Some Static Value", display = "Custom Display Text 111", };
        SecondValue = new ComboBoxDataType() { id = 2, data = dynamicName, display = dynamicName, };

        SelectedItem = FirstValue;
        SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

public class ComboBoxDataType : PropertyChangeHelper
{
    private long _id { get; set; }
    public long id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _data { get; set; }
    public string data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _display { get; set; }
    public string display
    {
        get { return _display; }
        set
        {
            _display = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class PropertyChangeHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The reason for all of this you might ask...well this adds for flexibility instead of "hacking" things or adding in extra complexity in the XAML with a data trigger. You are working purely off of logic using an easy to manipulate data class.

Comment: While this solution works, the reason I don't bind the Content of the first combobox is because I need it to not be the value of the underlying item. Meaning, I don't want to use Item2, I need to use a constant value. That's the main reason I can't just use a collection, as I need to maintain FirstValue as it's provided, but display a different text value in the combobox if that makes sense.

Comment: @marisa So I am not really clear what you are looking to do here then. Do you want a static value to always display in the edit bar of the `combobox`? Or are you looking to have an initial string to display but then display the selected item after?

Comment: I need a combobox to have two values. The FirstValue should use for display not its given name (provided in Item2), but instead always display as "Custom Display Text 111". The context here is the two values are names of companies, but FirstValue will always be my company or a subsidiary of my company. For ease of comprehension I want to always display FirstValue as "My Parent Company Name", even if the actual FirstValue refers to a subsidiary. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've tweaked my example code to be a little more straightforward and to focus on the issue at hand.

Comment: @Marisa I am sorry, but still not making sense. A `ComboBox` has essentially 2 primary elements: The `EditBox` and the `DropdownBox`. For your example you have 3 variables. What is in the `EditBox` and 2 values in the `DropdownBox`. Please tell me what you want in each of those boxes when the `ComboBox` initially loads AND after an item is selected.

Comment: @Marisa It is important to also remember that `SelectedValue` and `SelectedIndex` represent whatever `ComboBox` item you have selected. They will NEVER be anything else. If you want the `EditBox` to be different, you will have to modify the style of the `ComboBox` as the default will not do what you want it to do.

Comment: At all times there are only two items in the DropdownBox: Item1 (which displays as CustomItem1) and Item2 (which displays as Item2). The code I have currently posted handles this perfectly when the user interacts with the control (i.e., if they select Item1 the control displays "CustomItem1" and the SelectedValue binding contains Item1).

Where it fails is when I try to default the selection on load of the control to Item1. Despite using the same reference to populate the DropdownBox items and to set the bound selected value, the control does not select Item1.

Comment: @Marisa My code would have done what you wanted had you just changed back the `ComboBoxItem Content` to what you had in your original question and for less code.

Comment: I ran your code, and the combobox is null when it runs (even after I added SelectedValue = FirstValue to the ctor). While it does correctly handle the text customization, it still cannot default the selected value. You can see this for yourself if you add a button and do a Console.WriteLine on the selected value for the combobox. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Marisa I was aware of the value being null, however since you are not using a collection, there is no need to call `SelectedValue` or even use it. You can determine which `ComboBox` value is selected via the `SelectedIndex` and then reference either `FirstValue` or `SecondValue` accordingly. If you really want to use `SelectedValue` then a combination of my answer and the other persons would work well. I will post it.

Comment: @Marisa I updated my answer significantly but actually used a completely different yet less complex approach that I have used in the past. I tested this thoroughly and I like the way it works much better due to flexibility. Hope this helps.