# Databinding with DisplayMemberPath escapes underscore in menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

Ok, so we have a recent file menu option. We databind the MenuItem entries using MVVM and supply the DisplayMemberPath. But WPF escapes the string so underscore is displayed as an underscore instead as the accesskey

[image]

```
<MenuItem x:Name="RecentScripts" DisplayMemberPath="Caption" Header="Recent _Files" cal:Message.Attach="OpenRecentScript($orignalsourcecontext)">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource IconOpen}"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/recet_files_shortcut/FreePIE.GUI/Views/Main/Menu/MainMenuView.xaml#L35

We also have custom theme, but disabling style for MennuItem does not help
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/recet_files_shortcut/FreePIE.GUI/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml#L1921

Comment: Can you bind [access text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext(v=vs.110).aspx) directly?
`<MenuItem  ...>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource IconOpen}"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
<AccessText>_0</AccessText>
</MenuItem>`

Comment: You need to specify the Header Template and use `Label` that should fix your problem. reason why is because the default template uses `TextBlock` and TextBlock doesn't use the underscore.

Comment: But the same template works for none databound menuitems, look at the screenshot Recent Files has its accesstext

Comment: @3615 Your example gives "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

Comment: @Anders Yes, right, it should've been MenuItem.AccessText, but MenuItem doesn't support AccessText. Another way could be value converter that returns AccessText element, but looking at your implementation it doesn't look like an easy fit, so ItemTemplate seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the DisplayMemberPath with ItemTemplate. Like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18273473/5246145) DisplayMemeberPath is

> a template for a single property, shown in a TextBlock

As @XAMlMAX mentioned TextBlock doesn't support AccessText, while Label does.

```
            <MenuItem x:Name="RecentScripts" Header="Recent _Files" cal:Message.Attach="OpenRecentScript($orignalsourcecontext)">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource IconOpen}"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Caption}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
```