# DisplayMemberPath not working for ListBox with custom ListBoxItem control

Tags: wpf

I've configured ListBox to use custom `ControlTemplate` for it self and custom ControlTemplate for `ListBoxItem`. Unfortunately such change disables the default behvaiour of `DisplayMemberPath` property.

```
// resource dictionary of ListBox control template
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="CustomListBox" TargetType="ListBox" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
   <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
       <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False">
           <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"  />
       </ScrollViewer>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
//trigger code omitted
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomListBox}"></Setter>
</Style>




// resource dictionary of ListBoxItem control template
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3" Padding="6 6" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="White" Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <Label Height="3"></Label>

        </StackPanel>
 </ControlTemplate>
 // trigger code omitted
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItem}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath" Value="MatchText"></Setter>
</Style>
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" DisplayMemberPath="MyCustomText">
```

The DataContext of `listBox` is set using code. If I omit setting `CustomListBoxItem` as the control template, than it works as expected. How do you enable `DisplayMemberPath` when using custom control templates for `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your output window?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18273415/1136211)? DisplayMemberPath won't work when you explicitly set a template.

Comment: Nice find. No errors in output window. Googled 4 times and only found ComboBox related questions. I assume this works if you don't use custom ControlTemplate. How exactly do I port  DataTemplate to ListBoxItem control template?

Comment: Or ListBox control template.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but instead of using DisplayMemberPath you could simple have `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCustomText}"/>` in the ControlTemplate.

Comment: Ohh. I tried adding elements as a children of ContentPresenter. That didn't work. removing the ContentPresenter and just placing my own  elements worked as expected. Thank you.